# How to find the path of lowest cost in a 2D Matrix using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, matrix

I want to find the path of lowest cost in a 2D Matrix and here are some images associated with this:

Given a 2D Matrix, I want to traverse along the three allowed paths: 1) horizontally, 2) diagonally top right or 3) diagonally bottom right.

Here is the code I have so far to find the minimum cost:

```
var input2 = [ [2,3,4], [2,6,8], [3,4,6] ]

func calculate() {
    var sums = [Int]()
    var tmp = [Int]()
    for o in input2 {
        for i in o {
            tmp.append(i)
        }
        sums.append(tmp.min()!)
    }
}
```

I'm stuck at this point of calculating the minimum and unable to enforce the neighboring indices like horizontal or diagonal movements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, use Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path. Here's a quick unoptimized solution I came up with.

```
let M = 3
let N = 3
var input = [[2,3,4],
             [2,6,8],
             [3,4,6]]
var shortestPaths = [[Int]](repeatElement([Int](repeatElement(Int.max, count: N)), count: M))

func search(_ currentPosition: (Int, Int),
                 _ path: [(Int, Int)],
                 _ totalCost: Int,
                 _ shortestPath: [(Int, Int)],
                 _ lowestCost: Int)
    -> ([(Int, Int)], Int) {
        if (totalCost >= lowestCost) {
            return (shortestPath, lowestCost)
        }
        let (i, j) = currentPosition
        var lowestCost = lowestCost
        var shortestPath = shortestPath
        if (currentPosition == (M - 1, N - 1)) {
            return (path, totalCost)
        }
        if (shortestPaths[i][j] < totalCost) {
            return (shortestPath, lowestCost)
        }
        shortestPaths[i][j] = totalCost
        if (i > 0) {
            if (j > 0) {
                let result = search((i - 1, j - 1), path + [(i - 1, j - 1)], totalCost + input[i - 1][j - 1], shortestPath, lowestCost)
                if (result.1 < lowestCost) {
                    lowestCost = result.1
                    shortestPath = result.0
                }
            }
            if (j < N - 1) {
                let result = search((i - 1, j + 1), path + [(i - 1, j + 1)], totalCost + input[i - 1][j + 1], shortestPath, lowestCost)
                if (result.1 < lowestCost) {
                    lowestCost = result.1
                    shortestPath = result.0
                }
            }
            let result = search((i - 1, j), path + [(i - 1, j)], totalCost + input[i - 1][j], shortestPath, lowestCost)
            if (result.1 < lowestCost) {
                lowestCost = result.1
                shortestPath = result.0
            }
        }
        if (i < M - 1) {
            if (j > 0) {
                let result = search((i + 1, j - 1), path + [(i + 1, j - 1)], totalCost + input[i + 1][j - 1], shortestPath, lowestCost)
                if (result.1 < lowestCost) {
                    lowestCost = result.1
                    shortestPath = result.0
                }
            }
            if (j < N - 1) {
                let result = search((i + 1, j + 1), path + [(i + 1, j + 1)], totalCost + input[i + 1][j + 1], shortestPath, lowestCost)
                if (result.1 < lowestCost) {
                    lowestCost = result.1
                    shortestPath = result.0
                }
            }
            let result = search((i + 1, j), path + [(i + 1, j)], totalCost + input[i + 1][j], shortestPath, lowestCost)
            if (result.1 < lowestCost) {
                lowestCost = result.1
                shortestPath = result.0
            }
        }
        if (j > 0) {
            let result = search((i, j - 1), path + [(i, j - 1)], totalCost + input[i][j - 1], shortestPath, lowestCost)
            if (result.1 < lowestCost) {
                lowestCost = result.1
                shortestPath = result.0
            }
        }
        if (j < N - 1) {
            let result = search((i, j + 1), path + [(i, j + 1)], totalCost + input[i][j + 1], shortestPath, lowestCost)
            if (result.1 < lowestCost) {
                lowestCost = result.1
                shortestPath = result.0
            }
        }
        return (shortestPath, lowestCost)
}

let shortPath = search((0, 0), [(0, 0)], input[0][0], [], Int.max)
print(shortPath)

//output:
//([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)], 14)
```

This solution finds the shortest path from the top level corner to the lower right, but you can easily adjust it by changing the starting conditions and the comparison operation inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Dijkstra algorithm, here is a [Swift implementation](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Dijkstra%20Algorithm)

Comment: This is the right answer. Dijkstra algorithm is perfect here. +1

Answer (score -1):

Ref - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/min-cost-path-dp-6/

```swift
class Solution {
    
    var input: [[Int]] = [[Int]]()
    
    func findMinCostPath(input: [[Int]], row: Int, column: Int) -> Int {
        self.input = input
        return minCost(row, column)
    }
    
    func minCost(_ row: Int, _ column: Int) -> Int {

        guard row >= 0 && column >= 0
        else {
            return Int.max
        }

        if row == 0 && column == 0 {
            return input[0][0]
        } else {
            let minCosts = min(minCost(row - 1, column - 1),
                               minCost(row - 1, column),
                               minCost(row, column - 1))
            if minCosts == Int.max {
                return minCosts
            } else {
                return input[row][column] + minCosts
            }
        }
    }
}

let input = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 8 , 2], [1, 5, 3]]
print(Solution().findMinCostPath(input: input, row: 2, column: 2))
```